# fire event when div loads

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div on a page. I want to with jquery, when the div loads a function is fired and I can alter its style based on a set of conditions. Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to do this, when the DOM is ready.

Put this somewhere in a `<script>`:

```
$(function() {

    $('#id_of_div').css({...});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could try

```
<div>...content...</div>
<script>functionToRunWhenDivIsLoaded()</script>
```